# npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL - execute function with json parameter is not working

Tags: c#, docker, entity-framework-core, npgsql, linux-containers

Database: Postgresql

ORM: Entity framework core with Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL

Tried to call below fuction passing product list as json

```
dbContext.product.FromSqlRaw("SELECT pa.usp_set_product({0})", productjson).ToList();
```

return error as : "42883: function pa.usp_set_product(text) does not exist"

Then tried with below

```
dbContext.product.FromSqlRaw(@"SELECT pa.usp_set_product('" + productjson+ "')").ToList();
```

returns error: " Input string was not in a correct format "

Then tried below which works fine

```
 using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand(@"SELECT pa.usp_set_product(@productjson)", conn))
   {
    cmd.Parameters.Add(new NpgsqlParameter("productjson", NpgsqlDbType.Json) { Value = productjson});
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
```

Any idea, please-

1. why FromSqlRaw with JSON parameter is not working
2. is there any drawback using NpgsqlCommand - does it support Linux-container(docker)

Thanks,

@paul

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you include a parameter value in FromSqlRaw, it will be sent as the default corresponding PG type; I'm assuming that your `productjson` is a .NET string, which maps to a PG `text`, not `json`. The result is the same as your lower-level code using NpgsqlCommand, but without specifying `NpgsqlDbType.Json`.

EF Core also allows you to pass a DbParameter instance instead of a raw value, so you should be able to do the following:

```
var jsonParam = new NpgsqlParameter("productjson", NpgsqlDbType.Json);

dbContext.product.FromSqlRaw("SELECT pa.usp_set_product(@jsonParam)", jsonParam).ToList();
```

More information is available [on this doc page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql).

*Note: never concatenate or interpolate a string into the SQL of FromSqlRaw - that is vulnerable to SQL injection. Carefully read [the EF docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/raw-sql) for more information.*

*Note2: consider using the PostgreSQL `jsonb` type instead of `json`. You can read about the differences [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html).*

Answer (score -2):

Is there a reason you are not using LINQ for the queries?
It's easier, widely used, and optimized for most of the queries you would need.
It would look something like this, provided you create a Product entity:

```
DbContext.Products.Add(new Product() { ProductName = "Test Product", Weight = 5, ... }
await DbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Then if you want to retrieve product with id productId:

```
Product product = await DbContext.Products.FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == productId);
```

You need all deleted products?

```
List<Product> deletedProducts = await DbContext.Products.Where(p => p.DeletionTime != null).ToListAsync();
```

*(Those examples rely on you adding the needed properties to the Product entity, like Id and DeletionTime)*

Comment: The OP asked about executions stored functions, the suggestion to use LINQ here isn't relevant.

Comment: Maybe he doesn't know about LINQ, I don't see why would he write such simple queries raw.

Comment: He's not really writing queries, he's invoking functions... We don't know what's in them.